# Is it possible to remove an onBeforeUnmount lifecycle hook?

Tags: vuejs3

I want to do some cleanup when a component is unmounted and I thought that registering ***and unregistering*** onBeforeUnmount hooks could be a way to do it. Per the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html), I don't see a way to unregister onBeforeUnmount lifecycle hooks.

I know I can set up my own at-onBeforeUnmount-cleanup management, but if Vue can do it nicely, I'd prefer Vue over rolling my own. Anyone know if Vue can unregister hooks?

Comment: i believe vue takes care of that, you should take care only of resources allocated by you

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev sorry, perhaps I'm unclear. I'm talking about cleaning up MY resources using onBeforeUnmount. Things like intervals and unfired timeouts.

Comment: added an answer with an interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqVU02PmzAQ/StTWolEmwX6sRdKsu2ueui9PTU9EDwQN8ZGtslmhfjvHWNgWVX9imQpnnmeeTPv0QUfmyY6txikQWYKzRsLBm3b7PZ6L93hdaO0ha5QddNaZBvQWPZQalVDSA/D9wvUneDyNOaieLi54h7jTqGksWBVVQmErSu1KnNhcD0gfNZ1UhKlJcDUdbVaw3Y3PozOuWgRbsd2KchWCF/BnSz2g8wjZBbrRuQWhwhAdmitVRI+FIIXp+0+mPm88P/2we6LD81cstg/mko0uyz2S6LL/cw45Ybqza+oUBbP2QnO+Bk4I9wroaoBQpEhmcUz1WATtAY/S4uaxo1+GFJo0kLJr7JWLeXYcyXkXuJlwJStLCynIRdFVlEU5boy684BgX5+4ZzR6KT6Lzgq6FCLdqMOhcBcz3DO1g7aE2VrqGTJK+KrJDGm0OyCv1rsD8bqFmNMmCheBP/VYu4ItGSZmpLJHFuuyc/YebWeWW52iL8PrwGcjBGXBrW9w1JpXDFVtDUpHhUaScxPAt1tFZLO4XrjHxRHLphG+S35vo4sXuy9IgKD60M+UoGXIVw5rldXQ69+A2+T5H+s7ryWGvsokPzWHfLiVGmSkqXThm4hfEQh1ENIH1J4oKnC/neenLsMBYG0bpANUQJP+9K5NNxZL4WndteFEkpD9PrGjEt74Mwe0zdJ0lzGyBF5dbTpzVPkoDRDfa1zxluTwrsx0S/Gd0QGBkH/E/oTsGA=)

The OP clarified in the comments that he wants to clear for example an interval..

So first, the recommended hook for freeing allocated by a programmer resources is the `unmounted` hook:

https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#unmounted

If you do that in in `beforeunmounted` your DOM is still present and the freeing could affect it and introduce unwanted potential side-effects including jittering on the screen which is bad for UX.

But freeing resourses manually is always a **BAD** idea because it's sometimes forgotten.

Fortunately Vue allows us to wrap resources in a composable:

```
import {onUnmounted} from 'vue';

export function useInterval(...args){

    const id = setInterval(...args);
    onUnmounted(() => clearInterval(id));
}
```

And use it:

```
<script setup>

import {ref} from 'vue';
import {useInterval} from './useInterval';

const toggle = ref(false);

let num = 0;

useInterval(() => {
  toggle.value = !toggle.value;
  $log.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), $log.children[0]).textContent = 'interval #' + num++;
}, 300);

</script>

<template>
  <div :style="{background: toggle ? 'yellow' : 'blue'}"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>
div{
  transition: background-color .15s;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like `onUnmounted` is what I was thinking for cleanup hooks. Mostly, I was wondering if spamming Vue with a bunch of lifecycle hooks was supported/recommended/not-recommended - and by "spamming" I mean registering a hypothetically/arbitrarily large number of cleanup hooks.
The rolled-my-own solution was a simple `const cleanupHooks = new Set()`  of functions to be called at `unmount` - so it was only one `onUnmounted` hook, but it loops through and calls all the functions in `cleanupHooks`.

Comment: @crunk1 hooks are just functions, not a problem to have many and composables actually promote that